# Площадь пересечения двух полигонов

Tags: mysql

Приветствую!

Возникла нужда найти площадь пересечения двух полигонов.

[Intersection(g1,g2)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/functions-that-create-new-geometries-from-existing-ones.html#function_intersection) - в мануале есть функция.

А вот когда делаю в запросе `SELECT Intersection(P1.polygon, P2.polygon)`, выдается ошибка "Function does not exists", остальные функции (`Intersects`, `Within`, ...) работают нормално.

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там есть строчка, на которую вы возможно не обратили внимание

> These functions are not implemented in
> MySQL. (Эти функции не реализованы в
> MySQL.)